# first loop stops when the second starts

Tags: javascript

I want to use a for loop in another for loop to get the content of an xml file.
The problem is that when the second loop starts the first one stops.
**javascript code:**

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('usr');
for (i=0; i <= x.length; i++) {
    var y = x[i].childNodes;
    for(n=0; n <= y.length; n++) {
        var z = y[n].childNodes[0];
        document.write(z.nodeValue);
    }
}
```

**xml code:**

```
<usr><age>30</age><location>uk</location></usr>
<usr><age>25</age><location>usa</location></usr>
```

**And the output is:**

```
30uk
```

It should be 30uk25usa

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "when the second loop starts the first one stops".

Comment: Well yeah...it has to run through the inner loop completely, then restart the outer loop and repeat... your inner loop would be useless if the outer loop kept processing.

Comment: Shouldn't your for loops' second condition only go to `i < x.length` and `n < y.length`?  This probably generates an error when it looks for a second xml element in the inner loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both of your loops, you will iterate one too many times.

`i=0; i<=x.length` should be `i = 0; i < x.length` and same for the inner loop.

Iterating one too many times generates an error, which breaks the execution

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the total result that you want outside of the first loop, and then use `document.write()` after the outer loop completes:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('usr');
var zTotal = '';
for (i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var y = x[i].childNodes;
    for(n=0; n < y.length; n++) {
        var z = y[n].childNodes[0];
        zTotal += z.nodeValue;
    }
}
document.write(zTotal);
```

Comment: It should also be `<` and not `<=`:  `i < x.length` and `n < y.length)`.